# How to enable virtualization via PowerShell on Win10, HP laptop?

Tags: windows-10, bios, powershell, virtualization

How to enable virtualization via PowerShell on Win10, HP laptop?

Reason why I am not doing it this way:

Go to Windows Settings
Click on Update & Security
Now click on Recovery
Click Restart now under Advanced startup
Go to Troubleshoot
Click on Advanced Options
Now click on UEFI Firmware Settings
Click Restart.

--> My monitor on the laptop is broken, and thus I use an external monitor, when I go restart, I see the broken monitor "light up", but this restartu modus doesnt switch on the external monitor...

Comment: It's not possible to activate hardware virtualization from within Windows.

Comment: While the display is blank, press the f10 key to enter the BIOS settings menu. It might show up at the external screen after you enter BIOS

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HP BCU tool](https://ftp.hp.com/pub/caps-softpaq/cmit/HP_BCU.html) to change BIOS setup from Windows.
To create, save, and deploy the configuration settings, complete the following procedure:

1. Run the program BIOSConfigUtility.exe or BiosConfigUtility64.exe
   using the /GetConfig:config.txt command-line parameter.

Batch script:

```
if %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==AMD64 (BiosConfigUtility64.exe /GetConfig:"BIOS_config.txt") else (BiosConfigUtility.exe /GetConfig:"BIOS_config.txt")
```

2. Edit the obtained file config.txt. Remove properties that you do not
   want to change and modify the other properties.

Example of the config file:

```
BIOSConfig 1.0
;
; Originally created by BIOS Configuration Utility
; Version: 4.0.1.1
; Date="2014-09-17" Time="09:39:33" UTC="-5"
;
; Found 244 settings
;
Manufacturer
Hewlett-Packard
Product Name
HP ZBook 15
System Board ID
1909
Universal Unique Identifier(UUID)
7FAC190ABD17E411A132884C5F06E0FF
Processor Type
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4900MQ CPU
SKU Number
D5H49AV#ABA
Warranty Start Date
00/00/0000
Processor Speed
2.80GHz
Sunday
*Disable
Enable
```

In the given config Sunday option is disabled by marking it with *.
So, you need to find a line that corresponds to virtualization and enable it with * sign.

Note: the needed option may or may not present depending on the model. In my HP x2 1030 G2 the following files to be changed (set * in front of Enabled instead of Disabled):

```
Virtualization Technology (VTx)
    *Disable
    Enable
Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VTd)
    *Disable
    Enable
```

If BIOS is password protected you also need to provide a password file to the same utility first.

3. Run BIOSConfigUtility.exe with the /SetConfig:config.txt
   command-line parameter to apply the settings contained in
   config.txt.

Refer to the full guide at [HP site](https://whp-aus2.cold.extweb.hp.com/pub/caps-softpaq/cmit/whitepapers/BIOS_Configuration_Utility_User_Guide.pdf).

Comment: when executing BiosConfigUtility.exe       and accessing the config.txt file                                             there is no corresponding line where to enable/disable virtualization

Comment: @NB13 accordingly you don't have this option in your BIOS and you can't manage it from Windows anyhow. As I mentioned that depends on the BIOS version only

Comment: if I repair my HP laptop screen, where can I then switch on virtualization?

Comment: VTx is a feature supported or not supported by CPU core. If there is no such option in BIOS then most probably your CPU doesn't support it. So there is nowhere where you can switch it on.

Answer (score -1):

It's an old problem with old solutions.

Some suggestions are mentioned in this post

[Cannot enter BIOS due to broken screen](https://superuser.com/questions/476933/cannot-enter-bios-due-to-broken-screen)

Comment: Links to other answers are not acceptable answers here at Super User.  If you had read the author's question you would know they are unable to use Advanced Startup.