# Hp pavilion g62 | How to enter bios with no display attached?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, bios, vga

Let me sumarise what im doing and what has happened:

so i have the hp g62 and it has no built in display attached to it (because its cracked, and yes, i removed the entire display assembly) and the only way i can view things is via an external display. it tryed all display outputs (vga, HDMI) and pressed the monitor output button (under f4) and it didn't do anything. so it has to be trying to display a video output to a non existing display as the closed sensor isnt detecting anything.

if anyone knows how to physicaly disable built in monitor output, please tell me

edit: i got recomended a nother question with the same problem, small issue, i already looked at it and tryed what the other user already did and didnt help. i dismantled the laptop and connected the display, put it back together, and closed the laptop and didnt do anything.

Comment: In most of the cases it works as intended after physically disconnecting the the broken internal monitor and no need to toggle screens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot enter BIOS due to broken screen](https://superuser.com/questions/476933/cannot-enter-bios-due-to-broken-screen)